# Centering Acronym

Tags: horizontal-alignment, acronyms

Anyone help me for centering the acronym (not align left like this example)? I tried `\begin{center}` but it's not possible.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}


\section{Intro}

In the early nineties, \acs{GSM} was deployed in many European

countries. \ac{GSM} offered for the first time international

roaming for mobile subscribers. The \acs{GSM}'s use of \ac{TDMA} as

its communication standard was debated at length. And every now

and then there are big discussion whether \ac{CDMA} should have

been chosen over \ac{TDMA}.



\section{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}[TDMA]
\acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
\acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
\acro{NA}[\ensuremath{N_{\mathrm A}}]{Number of Avogadro\acroextra{ (see \S\ref{Chem})}}
\acro{NAD+}[NAD\textsuperscript{+}]{Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide}
\acro{NUA}{Not Used Acronym}
\acro{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
\acro{UA}{Used Acronym}
\acro{lox}[\ensuremath{LOX}]{Liquid Oxygen}%
\acro{lh2}[\ensuremath{LH_2}]{Liquid Hydrogen}%
\acro{IC}{Integrated Circuit}%
\acro{BUT}{Block Under Test}%
\acrodefplural{BUT}{Blocks Under Test}%
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "centering" is somewhat ambiguous here, I think.  In its traditional sense, it would produce a result in which the bolded acronyms on the left would be misaligned with respect to each other, and the margin widths of each line could be completely different from the other.

In my mind that would be nearly impossible to read, so perhaps I take some liberty to suggest that what is being sought is a symmetric indent of the margins.  In this way, the acronyms would themselves remain aligned for easier reading.  Yet the whole block would be centered and indented.

To do that, I merely change the margins inside the `acronym` block by adding the line `\leftskip=1in\relax\rightskip=1in\relax`.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

In the early nineties, \acs{GSM} was deployed in many European
countries. \ac{GSM} offered for the first time international
roaming for mobile subscribers. The \acs{GSM}'s use of \ac{TDMA} as
its communication standard was debated at length. And every now
and then there are big discussion whether \ac{CDMA} should have
been chosen over \ac{TDMA}.

\section{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}[TDMA]
\leftskip=1in\relax\rightskip=1in\relax
\acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
\acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
\acro{NA}[\ensuremath{N_{\mathrm A}}]{Number of Avogadro\acroextra{ (see \S\ref{Chem})}}
\acro{NAD+}[NAD\textsuperscript{+}]{Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide}
\acro{NUA}{Not Used Acronym}
\acro{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
\acro{UA}{Used Acronym}
\acro{lox}[\ensuremath{LOX}]{Liquid Oxygen}%
\acro{lh2}[\ensuremath{LH_2}]{Liquid Hydrogen}%
\acro{IC}{Integrated Circuit}%
\acro{BUT}{Block Under Test}%
\acrodefplural{BUT}{Blocks Under Test}%
\end{acronym}

\section{Blah}

Continued

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good ideal but it's too manual. Because my documents have different between odd page and even page in align left and align right (for convenient publish book)

Comment: @Yuri I think I could customize the left and right skips as a function of evenness or oddness of page number, if it would solve your problem.